# Appending a variable outside the scope of a function in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I am trying to append jsonFile, however, I am not able to append jsonFile with a new NSString unless I use a mutuable variable for the parameter file in the function. I have found the solution of using "inout" but in this case I get the error of "scaping closures can only capture inout parameters explicitly by value file.append(jsonData)

```
var jsonFile: [NSString] = []

func function(file: inout [NSString]){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://parse.udacity.com/parse/classes/StudentLocation?limit=1")!)
    request.addValue("QrX47CA9cyuGewLdsL7o5Eb8iug6Em8ye0dnAbIr", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
    request.addValue("QuWThTdiRmTux3YaDseUSEpUKo7aBYM737yKd4gY", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil { // Handle error...
            return
        }
        let jsonData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        file.append(jsonData)
    }
    task.resume()
}

function(file: &jsonFile)

print(jsonFile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with asynchronous code. You should not use an `inout` parameter. Instead, you should be using a completion handler.

Something like the following will work:

```
var jsonFile: [String] = []

func function(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://parse.udacity.com/parse/classes/StudentLocation?limit=1")!)
    request.addValue("QrX47CA9cyuGewLdsL7o5Eb8iug6Em8ye0dnAbIr", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
    request.addValue("QuWThTdiRmTux3YaDseUSEpUKo7aBYM737yKd4gY", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data, error != nil {
            if let jsonData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                completion(jsonData)
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

function() { (string) in
    if let string = string {
        jsonFile.append(string)
    }

    print(jsonFile)
}
```

Note all of the other clean up. Don't use `NSString`, use `String`. Don't use `NSMutableURLRequest`, use `URLRequest` with `var`.